# Can abi.encodeWithSignature be optimized by pre-compute?

Tags: solidity, assembly

I have a proxy implementation with method `exchange` and delegator with method `exchange2` with the following code:

```
function exchange2(int128 i, int128 j, uint256 dx, uint256 min_dy) public {
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = delegationTarget.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("exchange(int128,int128,uint256,uint256)", i, j, dx, min_dy)
        );
        if (!success) {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                revert(string(result));
            } else {
                revert();
            }
        }
        // pay cashback
```

this simple code above has about 2k gas overhead vs following openzeppelin proxy code:

```
    function _delegate(address implementation) internal {
        //        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly {
        // Copy msg.data. We take full control of memory in this inline assembly
        // block because it will not return to Solidity code. We overwrite the
        // Solidity scratch pad at memory position 0.
            calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())

        // Call the implementation.
        // out and outsize are 0 because we don't know the size yet.
            let result := delegatecall(gas(), implementation, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)

        // Copy the returned data.
            returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())

            switch result
            // delegatecall returns 0 on error.
            case 0 { revert(0, returndatasize()) }
            default { return(0, returndatasize()) }
        }
    }
    fallback () external {
        _delegate(delegationTarget);
    }
```

The problem with oz code, I don't know how can I delegate call to `exchange` of implementation from  `exchange2` method of proxy.

Is there a way I can optimize `abi.encodeWithSignature` call if I know that `signature of exchange(int128,int128,uint256,uint256) - 0x3df02124`? It sounds wastfull to pass same string as an argument every time the function called.

Comment: I am not sure if it works this way, but since the first argument is constant, some of the functions logic could be evaluated at compile time. So it would be possible (if the compuler supports it, an I don't know if it does) that the compiler already does the optimization you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

> An approximation to abi.encodeWithSignature is abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256(signature)), abi.encode(parameters...))

You can save 0x3df02124 as byte4 variable in your contract and use an adaptation of the code above:

```
bytes4 functionSig = 0x3df02124
abi.encodePacked(functionSig, abi.encode(parameters...))
```

Comment: For my case (a single `uint256`) this costs about 250 more gas than just using `abi.encodeWithSignature` (Using Solidity `0.8.7` with optimizations at `200`). Deployment of the contract costs about `25000` additional gas.